# MyBatis - Simple selectOne is not working

Tags: mybatis

**Mybatis:**

Not sure whats going wrong.. But a basic SelectOne is not returning results.

Mapper:

```
<select id="getBackLog" parameterType="string"
    resultType="string">
select data_key from yfs_task_q where task_q_key = #{value}
</select>
```

Method:

> dataKey = (String) session.selectOne("OMSWatchMappers.getBackLog", agent);
>   logger.debug("@Backlog=" + dataKey);

Logs:

```
02:01:34.786 [main] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Openning JDBC Connection
02:01:35.890 [main] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Created connection 2092843500.
02:01:35.961 [main] DEBUG c.b.o.r.OMSWatchMappers.getBackLog - ooo Using Connection   [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@7cbe41ec]
02:01:35.961 [main] DEBUG c.b.o.r.OMSWatchMappers.getBackLog - ==>  Preparing: select data_key from yfs_task_q where task_q_key = ? 
02:01:36.126 [main] DEBUG c.b.o.r.OMSWatchMappers.getBackLog - ==> Parameters: 201101070640191548867209(String)
02:01:36.249 [main] DEBUG OMSWatchDAOImpl - @Backlog=null
02:01:36.250 [main] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Resetting autocommit to true on JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@7cbe41ec]
02:01:36.250 [main] DEBUG o.a.i.t.jdbc.JdbcTransaction - Closing JDBC Connection [oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@7cbe41ec]
02:01:36.250 [main] DEBUG o.a.i.d.pooled.PooledDataSource - Returned connection 2092843500 to pool.
```

This record exists in the database.

```
select data_key from yfs_task_q where task_q_key = '201101070640191548867209';

DATA_KEY               
------------------------
201101070636011548866830
```

If I change the mapper to add the parameter directly, it returns the result.

Mapper:

```
<select id="getBackLog" parameterType="string"  resultType="string">
select data_key from yfs_task_q where task_q_key = '201101070640191548867209'
</select>
```

Logs:

```
02:38:52.746 [main] DEBUG c.b.o.r.OMSWatchMappers.getBackLog - ==>  Preparing: select     data_key from yfs_task_q where task_q_key = '201101070640191548867209' 
02:38:52.942 [main] DEBUG c.b.o.r.OMSWatchMappers.getBackLog - ==> Parameters: 
02:38:53.096 [main] DEBUG OMSWatchDAOImpl - @Backlog=201101070636011548866830
```

There is something basic I'm missing here. Any help in pointing out will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.. The DB Column was CHAR(30) and I was passing String object to Mybatis. The WHERE clause comparison was failing ...

`ColValue [201101070640191548867209      ] <> Input [201101070640191548867209]`

Changed query to

`select data_key from yfs_task_q where trim(task_q_key) = #{value}`

Still need to do some more research to see if there is any flag / configuration I can set to force MyBatis ignore the padded spaces in the col value.

If anyone knows about mybatis coig, please post the same. But for this issue posted, cause is found and I can move on :)

Note: I'm not sure why these columns are CHAR and not VARCHAR.. its a 3rd party app table.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `agent` in your method is actually a string.

Answer (score -1):

Pass as `id.trim()` and that worked for character based `where` clause columns.